# Bootstrap modal + unobtrusive client validation

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, unobtrusive-validation

In our ASP.NET MVC 4 project, we are using bootstrap modal pop to get some input from user,is there any possibilities to use unobtrusive client validation to show the errors in validationsummary with in the popup?

Comment: The answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902581/unobtrusive-validation-not-working-with-dynamic-content